# How do I access the Drupal class from a standalone PHP file?

Tags: 8, external-scripts

How do I use the `\Drupal` class in an standalone PHP file?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of drush [php-script](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/core/php-script/) command.

```
drush scr /path/to/file.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use drush in a shebang, if you have drush installed.

This is an example for a standalone php file, where you can access Drupal classes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush

$sitename = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name');

echo "This is the site $sitename\n";
```

See http://www.drush.org/en/master/shellscripts/

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the drupal core components are composer packages you can load them quite easily using composer:

```
composer require drupal/component_name
```

You just need to require the composer's autoloader into your PHP script and you can quite easily use these classes in your own scripts.